Cant install msodbcsql17 on debian 12
I'm running Debian 12 on a RasperryPI. I'm trying to connect to a SQL server (Microsoft ODBC 17) using pyodbc, but I can't seem to install the needed components.
Per Microsoft's instructions, I have:

Downloaded Microsoft's public key file: curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.asc

Downloaded the package corresponding to Debian 12: curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/12/prod.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list

Downloaded Microsoft's gpg file: curl -fsSL https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/microsoft-prod.gpg (instructions)

Updated packages: sudo apt-get update

Ran sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17 and it returns with: E: Unable to locate package msodbcsql17


I'm not sure what else to try here. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

I've had the same issue and found a few pages to help. The first thing you need to do is update the signatures for Microsoft.

check version of Debian

lsb_release -a

Article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1328834/debian-12-public-key-is-not-available
"The problem here is apt changed the way it verified signatures. And MS has not updated the process for Debian 12.
I found the solution on another article with Ubuntu. Use this command to properly import the signature":

curl -fsSL https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/microsoft-prod.gpg
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.asc   && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/12/prod.list | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list && apt-get update && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17 unixodbc-dev mssql-tools

Article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linux/packages#command-examples-for-using-the-linux-repository-service
Distribution and version

curl -sSL -O https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/12/packages-microsoft-prod.deb

Install the repo config package:

dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb

Delete the repo config package after installing

rm packages-microsoft-prod.deb

Update package index files:

apt-get update
HTH.
